# How much bandwidth will used if i play same video on multiple video element?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, bandwidth

I am streaming live video in `HTML5` `video` element. I want to display that video on different different layout using that video stream object.
I have played that same video on 3 `video` element by fetching `srcObject` using `js` and passing that `srcObject` to all other video element  and it is working.

I want to know that playing same video on multiple htlm `video` element will consume more bandwidth than it's original bandwidth ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in DevTools to see how much data your page is downloading?  This may be browser specific.